# Instruct web browser to redirect to localhost if open php file

Tags: php, redirect, browser, xampp

I tried to open the php file to see the results I was working on, but to open the file I had to manually change the url from **.../httdocs/** to **localhost/**, it's bit waste time

Example

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/dashboard/index.php
```

to

```
http://localhost/dashboard/index.php
```

And the question is, can I instruct the web browser to auto-direct the file to local server when i open the php file?
Thank you

> I use google chrome web browser and local server from XAMPP

Comment: Maybe you can add some Javascript that will redirect the user to localhost.

Answer (score 1):

well, use a text editor called **brackets** its live preview helps you accomplish that it has an experimental feature which automatically redirects you to the page you are working on without a hassle...